# TypeError: this is undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-harmony

```
function foo(obj, method, ...args) {
  if (!(method in obj)) return null;
  try {
    alert(!!obj); //shows true
    return obj[method].apply(obj, args);
  }
  catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

When I call `foo` with a defined object, a valid method of it and some args, it shows:
`TypeError: this is undefined.`

What does this mean?

I thought `this` would be important here because I'm using `apply` whose 1st param will be used as `this` inside the method invoked. But here `obj` is valid and it doesn't even invoke the required method. An error is caught even before.

(`...args` means any extra arguments passed to `foo` after `obj` and `method` will be pushed into an array `args` which can be used by `foo`)

**EDIT:** `...args` is valid. It's ES6.

**EDIT**: My code seems perfectly fine. I'm trying to check and see if the called function has something wrong. Sorry if that is the case.

**EDIT**: I'm sorry, the problem turned out to be with the method that was being invoked. I had said otherwise, but I was confused.

There was another callback in it.

```
array.forEach(function (a) { // do something with 'this'});
```

`this` was obviously being undefined since it didn't refer to the object.

Comment: Are you really having `...args` in your code? That's a syntax error, unless you are using ES6 (but you should tell us at least). http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:rest_parameters. If I change `...args` to `args` and pass an array, it works just fine.

Comment: @FelixKling, I am using ES6. Sorry  I didn't tell it

Comment: How are you executing the code? Natively trough Node.js or are you converting to ES5 first?

Comment: @FelixKling, I'm using the Mozilla framework. Don't know how it happens internally.

Comment: Should I write my last edit as an answer or delete the question?

Answer (score 1):

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8LNUL/1/)

I changed your function to this.  First we narrow down the parameters, to make sure they are of the correct types.  We need an `obj` and a `method`.  Furthermore, `obj[method]` better be a function, because we're trying to `call` it.

```
function foo(obj, method) {
  if (typeof obj === 'undefined' 
   || typeof method !== 'string' 
   || typeof obj[method] !== 'function') {
          return null;
  }
```

I'm not sure how ES6 works, and have no way to test it, but this should continue to work.  If you can get it to work without, it's an easy change (removing this line, and adding a parameter).

```
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return obj[method].apply(obj, args);e);
}
```

We can test it by giving it a `Person`.

```
function Person(){
    this.say_name = function(first, last){
        alert('My name is ' + first + ' ' + last);
    };
}

var Me = new Person();
foo(Me, "say_name", "John", "Doe"); // shows "My name is John Doe"
```

Just ask if you need further explanation.

Comment: Could you also explain what is wrong with the OP's code? I mean, there must be a reason why you suggested this change.